# exchange 2007 how to delete messages from specific mailboxes

Tags: windows, powershell, exchange-server

I would like to run a powershell command to delete messages send to specific individuals on a specific date containing a specific subject.

Can you please advice me or point me into the right direction on a powershell script that would do this?

Thank you very much for your guidance.

i found a cool script:

```
#Add Exchanage snapin
add-pssnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.Admin

#Get list of mailboxes to delete
$users=Get-Content C:\MailboxesToDelete.txt

#For Loop to delete them
foreach ($user in $users)
{
#Print to screen user mailbox to delete
$user
#Delete AD user and Mailbox
Remove-Mailbox -Identity $user -Permanent $true -whatif

#Remove the -whatif if you want to really delete some users.
}
```

from here:

http://randomtechminutia.wordpress.com/2012/05/03/powershell-script-to-delete-exchange-mailboxes-in-mass/

but this deletes mailboxes not messages!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the help for the `Export-Mailbox` cmdlet. More information here:

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb266964(v=exchg.80).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb266964%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)